# shell script parsing data to variables then update a database

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I have a device on my network that is posting data to an html page.  I need to be able to collect the data from the page and insert it into my database so I can have historical reference to the data.  I am able to use the following command to retrieve the fields from the site.  The result returns three numbers separated by a line break.

I would like to run this as a linux cron job, so I would like to use a linux script to:

1. save the data (numbers) to variables
2. connect to my database and insert the data in a table

My command line to retrieves the information is below.  This works great for parsing out the data from the device:

```sh
 curl -s http://local_device.com/dtm.html?address=C5:0 | grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=[^0-9]+(C5:2<|C5:6<|C5:13))'
```

Comment: OK, if it works great, what's the problem?

Comment: You should put the URL in quotes, since it contains shell wildcard characters.

Answer (score 1):

see below for a reference, since they are numbers, I did not quote them:

```
set -- $(curl -s http://local_device.com/dtm.html?address=C5:0 | grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=[^0-9]+(C5:2<|C5:6<|C5:13))')
C5_2=$1
C5_6=$2
C5_13=$3
mysql -e "
   INSERT INTO db.table VALUES ($C5_2, $C5_6, $C5_13) 
"
```